# Django,MSSQL server query and pagination

Tags: sql-server, django, django-models, pyodbc

This is a sample of my MSSQL server table

Employeetable

```
emp_id  name  status 
EMP001  A     STATUS-A
EMP001  A     STATUS-B
EMP002  B     STATUS-C
EMP001  A     STATUS-D
EMP002  B     STATUS-D
EMP003  C     STATUS-C
```

Now in my app front end page there is a table in which each employee is listed once in the table and expanding each employee will show their every available status. I had tried to fetch using pyodbc

For Example:

```
EMPID   NAME 
EMP001  A
---STATUS-A  #After expanding the EMP001 row it shows all the status of EMP001
---STATUS-B
---STATUS-D
EMP002  B
EMP003  C
```

So how can we use pagination in this consider there are about 200K records and about 100K distinct employees

Comment: You mean like a treeview ? You see a list of employees and when you click on an employee than detail rows are shown, just like in windows explorer for example. That has nothing to do with pagination, but with master-detail, it is the client that shows the data that should handle this. Showing a list of 100K employees is however indeed pointless, such a screen I would open empty and only after some filters have been filled by the user I would fetch the rows

Comment: @GuidoG only 50 disitinct employee will be shown first

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to do it:

1.lazy loading

2. Use arraysize parameter in the cursor  that mean you will not fetch all data from database , but batch calling, this one takes less memory but more reads from DB, which can make your app work slower, from the other hand if more users only use first or second page this will be more effective